# How to create a take all express route?

Tags: regex, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to create a forward proxy server in nodejs/express in which I want to create an endpoint in express that takes all other params and make it accessible through params object.

basically I want something like this:

```
app.get('/proxify/:path', function (req,res){
    res.send(Proxify(req.params.path))
})
```

so if a request comes for 'myproxy.com/proxify/somewebsite.com/path/to/some/site',
I would be able to access 'somewebsite.com/path/to/some/site' through req.params.path variable and make a request on that path.

Comment: Why not just use replace for that? Something like myPath = known_route.replace(known_route, ''); That'll leave you with the proxy'd call to the other site.

Comment: You mean I should  replace the '/' with something else on client side and then make the request?

Comment: no - create a middleware that will parse that path and store it on the request object so you can handle it properly in your app